# Regarding extracting feature vector for image processing

Tags: python, image-processing, feature-extraction

First, pardon me if the question is a little bit hard to be understood since I am still a novice and trying my best to express my problem.

I am trying to implement the method of detecting road lane from [Effective lane detection and tracking method using statistical modeling of color and lane edge-orientation](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5369883&tag=1) thesis (Maybe not all of you guys can access this thesis).

From the thesis:

"A proposed lane segmentation method uses two distinctive features when there is an input image `f (x, y)` ,`Z = [z1, z2 ]T` for classifying lane pixels: lane HSV color feature z1 and lane edge-orientation feature z2, which can be defines as `Z = [z1, z2]T = [I'(x, y), ø(x,y)]T`

What I want to know is, is the `Z` itself only has two elements, in which each element correspond to a pixel, which also means I will have `Z(x, y)` feature vectors?

Or will I only have one feature vector `Z` in which inside the vector already contains a long list of `I'` and `ø` of each pixel?

And, how can I store this feature vector with Python (By using certain library)? I already make some search but still a little bit confused. It would be helpful if at least someone can give me a keyword so I can search deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hilman, first thing is understanding about a feature vector, a feature is a description of your data using some properties of data(in this case pixel) for example mean or variance(or Color [r,g,b]) etc of data (pixel), or may be output of applying any transformation function(such as color space conversion) on your data (pixel) which converts your data into more appropriate form for classifying or making prediction purposes.

Here what i understand from your question description is, proposed algorithm taking HSV value(using color space conversion) of each pixel along with its gradient direction(phase), if you club them you will get 4 column vector for each pixel.  so if you talk about feature vector z it will consist [H, S, V, Phase] for each pixel along with class annotation of the pixel.

in python if you want to store a feature vector you can write a **[csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)** file of a numpy array.

Thank You